# android code to detect whether my android app user is online or not

Tags: android

I have developed a android application, have launched it in google play. It has been downloaded by many people (around 200-300) . Now my question is i want to know if my user is online or not. Actually i want to perform a particular action in my server for that user when the user is online. How can i know the user is online and currently viewing my app screen?

i have tried the below code , which can only say whether device has internet conncetion or not..

```
private boolean isOnline()
    {
        try
        {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting(); 
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

How can i know whether my user is viewing my app screen now? i hope there will be   a option available for this!

Comment: So, you can do like when user enters the app, and have internet connection, just update status of user to "Online" in your online database, inside your onResume(), and when user exits the app, update status to "offline". Actually, implementation of this includes both Front end and Backend code. Scope of your question is large.

Comment: hi chintan please check my comment to avinash answer

Comment: do you want check that on your server or on the Android device?

Comment: on the server would be very fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to have some code in `onResume` and `onPause` methods

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    isOnline(true);
    }
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    isOnline(false);
}
```

Comment: but i have many activity classes in my app. in which class should i put this code? (Based on the type of user, i have different kinds of user log in screen and corresponding activities)

Comment: @KPRanjith Generally we use this kind of code in main Activities where the user stays for long time. It does no harm in placing it in other Activities too..

Comment: ok avinash thanks for response lemme try this.. and let you know :)

Answer (score 1):

Implement Broadcast Receiver Class as follows which will send broadcast whenever internet is online:

```
public class InternetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        boolean isConnected = new ConnectionDetector(context)
                .isConnectedToInternet();
        if (isConnected) {
            //user is connected 
        }
    }

public boolean isConnectedToInternet(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null) 
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null) 
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }
}
```

In Manifest  define as :

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.InternetReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Hi Clair please check my comment to the avinash answer and i'll try this and let you know the result.