# What the best approach to handle offline and online user in app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile

I have an app and I want to handle online and offline users, which when user destroy the app from the background I have to send to the server that this user is offline now, otherwise send online

Comment: You can follow - 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406264/android-code-to-detect-whether-my-android-app-user-is-online-or-not

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947316/how-to-know-if-app-user-is-offline

Answer (score 0):

make a server request in onDestroy method
onDestroy: The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed.

```
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
}
```